# Naming conventions and field naming question for CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Okay so two questions very related:

1) Does following the naming convention for classes, controllers, database fields, etc. affect the framework's ability to work the way it was intended? (I'm a little new to working with a framework from the beginning of app development)

2) This question is more important if 1 is a yes. Say I have a table, A, that has 2 foreign keys pointing at the same table, B, but different entries (they're like edges of a graph that point at two vertices) how would I follow the naming convention of their database fields? All I can think to do is something like vertex_1_id and vertex_2_id but I don't know how the framework would handle that if the naming conventions are necessary for its functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
   It takes some time to learn the conventions, but they amortize later ("convention over configuration").
2. If a table contains two foreign keys, say vertex1_id and vertex2_id (<- following the CakePHP conventions), pointing to the same table, aliases are applied.

**Edit0:**
Maybe [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/172/Authentication#!/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together) is what you are looking for with regards to (2). Check the `foreignKey` part.

Comment: Sooo the vertex table called vertices will work fine with a table called edges with two fields, one called vertex1_id and vertex2_id? So this will work correctly without me having to explicitly code in my own name convention?

Comment: neither do I, don't know what screwed it up. i was multitasking heavily.

Comment: Haha yea easy to get caught up in that. Thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 2):

You can name everything anything, but then you will have to tell Cake more explicitly what's what. Naming conventions are just that, **conventions**, not rules. If you follow the conventions Cake will automatically know what belongs together. If you don't, you will have to write all the code explicitly that makes things work.